# Changing the value of a text box not updating the model inside a form in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

So I have been playing around trying to set the value of a text box for my unit tests. The text box is linked to the component model using ngModel. I have managed to get it all working in a simple example. However as soon as I put the text box inside a form tag it stops working and I was wondering if anyone could tell me why?

So I have the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  newOrgName:string = 'app';
}
```

With the following template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="newOrgName" name="app-input" id="app-input" type="text">
```

And the following unit test:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { async, TestBed, } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ],

    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it(`changing the value in the text box should update the model`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let el: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#app-input')).nativeElement;


    el.value = 'Bob';
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(app.newOrgName).toEqual('Bob');  
  }));
});
```

And it all works but as soon as I change the template to put the input in a form tag like so:

```
<form>
    <input [(ngModel)]="newOrgName" name="app-input" id="app-input" type="text">
</form>
```

The test fails and it says: "Expected 'app' to equal 'Bob'". So the model is no longer being updated. Why is this?

Comment: Try printing the value of **"el"** and see whether it's selecting the element perfectly or not?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with selection it comes back with <input _ngcontent-c0="" id="app-input" name="app-input" type="text" ng-reflect-name="app-input" ng-reflect-model="app" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"> for the test inside the form and the one outside the form.

Comment: What you mean by **"and the one outside the form"**? Do u have two inputs?

Comment: Sorry no I mean the test where the input is not inside a form.